# Exporting table data to excel from access

Tags: excel, ms-access, export-to-excel

I have a form where it presents the values of a table, which has links to other tables through the keys fields (most numerical fields ID), for the end user. In this form the user has the option to export the table information to an excel spreadsheet, the export function is working perfectly, however the worksheet fields are filled with the values of the primary fields keys of each other table that is used as a reference. Is there any way to export to excel any other column other than the a bound column?

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmd_Export_Excel_Click()

Luser = Environ("username")

desktop_path = "C:\Users\" & Luser & "\Desktop\DHB - DPAR.xlsx"

On Error GoTo SubError
 
    'For this to run, you'll need to replace the query name with your query and the file name
    'with a valid path on your machine
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "tblDPAR", _
    desktop_path
 
  
    MsgBox "File exported successfully", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "DHB - Design Dept"
   
SubExit:
    Exit Sub
   
SubError:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & "= " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "An error occured"
    GoTo SubExit

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess it's exports the values of the primary fields keys because it's set up like that. The bound column in the properties is the one that holds those values. The hard option is redesigning, but probably you could create a query to export to Excel the columns you want.

Comment: Yeah, you solved my headache. Created a query, changed the fields and used it as base to the vba code. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know yet how to tag the user how answered and helped me to solve this, but it's in the comments.

He suggested to create a query and use this as base to the export code. It's working now.